# Django dynamic model permission using request method

Tags: python, django, api, permissions, backend

I am working in a company which uses machines and molds to produce industrial parts. During the production process machines can malfunction so we created a frontend and backend for workers to register those error records. Recently engineers and managers from another departments joined to this system so **I needed to make sure who can do what in other word managing permissions**.

Relevant model:

```
class FaultRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    fault = models.ForeignKey(Fault, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    mold = models.ForeignKey(Mold, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    responsible_departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    status = models.ForeignKey(FaultRecordStatus, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    reason = models.TextField()
    temporary_action = models.TextField()
    permanent_action = models.TextField(null=True)
    duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    occured_at = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Relevant view:

```
class FaultRecordViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ModelPermission]
    serializer_class = FaultRecordSerializer
    queryset = FaultRecord.objects.prefetch_related(
        'user',
        'fault',
        'machine',
        'mold',
        'part',
        'material',
        'responsible_departments',
        'status'
    ).all().order_by('occured_at')
    model = FaultRecord
```

As we know Django creates [4 default permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) for models which are view, add, change and delete. Based on this I wanted to check user permissions by request method so I don't have to write permission class for every model. Also I don't want to use has_object_permission because I check post permission too.

Solution I found:

```
class ModelPermission(BasePermission):
    method_mapper = {
        'GET': 'view',
        'POST': 'add',
        'PUT': 'change',
        'PATCH': 'change',
        'DELETE': 'delete'
    }

    def get_model_permission(self, method, model):
        app_label = model._meta.app_label
        model_name = model._meta.model_name
        permission_name = self.method_mapper.get(method)
        return f'{app_label}.{permission_name}_{model_name}'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        permission = self.get_model_permission(request.method, view.model)
        return request.user.has_perm(permission)
```

I added model attribute to view class so get_model_permission returns required string to be able to use has_perm for me. With this I can create groups with permissions and set user groups. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything usefull for me. What do you think? I need opinions from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in right direction, but I would suggest using DjangoModelPermissions instead of BasePermission. DjangoModelPermissions implements the get_required_permissions and has_permission functions so, you need not write those functions yourself. If you don't want to check object permissions then assign DjangoModelPermissions in your viewset.

You are right about managing permissions with groups. Create groups and assign permissions to those groups and Then assign groups to users. You can also assign some permissions to a user directly if the situation demands. has_permission of DjangoModelPermissions by default check permission assigned to user as well as user groups.

Comment: I just checked source code of DjangoModelPermissions and that was what I need alsa what I wrote. Thank you.